# How to configure Apache to Angular And Spring Boot in Different Ports?

Tags: angular, apache, spring-boot, proxy

**I only found the example for the NGINX server, not for Apache.**

I made an web app with Angular4 that is in `/var/www/asicat` and is accessed in `http://myServerIP/asicat/`

This Angular4 app make AJAX calls to `/asicat-rs/*` as its API that is the backend written in Java Spring Boot.

Everything is set in application.properties, like:

```
server.contextPath=/asicat-rs
server.port=8092
server.use-forward-headers=true
```

But I don't know how to configure my Apache to: when receive `:80/asicat-rs` calls from Angular, Apache then should redirects to `:8092/asicat-rs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forward `/asicat-rs/*` requests to `http://localhost:8092/asicat-rs` with apache `mod_roxy`:

`ProxyPass "/asicat-rs/" "http://localhost:8092/asicat-rs/"
ProxyPassReverse "/asicat-rs/" "http://localhost:8092/asicat-rs/"`

I assume that your apache server and spring boot application are in the same server.

You can refer to : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: You should keep port in both lines

Comment: Thank you, very much! I just added slash after asicat-rs and it worked.